# is this iMac RAM compatible with my T530 Lenovo Lunchbox?

Tags: memory, upgrade, lenovo-laptop, imac

I'm looking to upgrade the RAM on my laptop from 8gb to 16gb. It seems that 8gb just doesn't cut it any more and I often find my RAM usage maxed out just by having a couple of tabs open on Firefox and Chrome.

I'm shopping around for laptop RAM and I stumbled across this:

http://www.msy.com.au/pc-components/9692-patriot-imac-so-dimm-16gb-kit8gx2-ddr3-1333-notebook-ram-psa316g1333sk.html

> Patriot iMac SO-DIMM 16GB Kit(8Gx2) DDR3 1333 Notebook RAM
>   PSA316G1333SK
>
> PC3-10600 (1333MHz) Data Rate
>
> 204-Pin Dual in-line memory module
>
> Non-ECC Unbuffered SODIMM
>
> 2 Rank Double-sided module
>
> 7.8US Refresh Interval (8192 CYCLES/64MS)
>
> 1.5V Power Requirement
>
> Auto and self refresh capability
>
> PCB height: 1181 (mil)
>
> Serial Presence-Detect (SPD)
>
> 100% tested
>
> RoHS Compliant

It sounds good, but I'm no hardware expert. I was wondering if this RAM is only compatible with apple iMacs (seeing as it says "iMac" in the description)? Or would it be compatible with my Lenovo "Lunchbox" T530?

Comment: Better asked on the hardware stack...

Comment: i didn't know there was one. I was told to post here by the folks on stackoverflow mainpage

Comment: It’s in the list of sites...

Comment: DDR3 is DDR3 it is not possible for memory to only work with specific hardware.  It might be incompatible with hardware, but it’s incompatible, for a specific reason.  There is no reason it shouldn’t be compatible with a Lenovo PC.   Just verify the Lenovo supports 16 GB modules

Comment: If you make that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Refer this for the compatible memory upgrades: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/IBMLenovoThinkPadT530T530i.html

Answer (score 0):

The link specifies the memory module as PC3-10600 (1333MHz) Data Rate - 16GB. Based on the Lenovo spec [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd024683) your laptop will only accept:

PC3-12800 memory modules with sizes of 2GB, 4GB, 8GB - up to 32GB

So the answer is NO, that module is not compatible with your laptop